# VSCode doesn't recognize g++ although everything seems to be correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

So I have been looking everywhere and nothing I try helps me.  This situation is quite unique.  I tried compiling a simple program in VSCode, and if gives me the following error:

```
g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program.
```

The trouble is I am POSITIVE that everything is set up the same way as on my laptop, I even followed my instructors instructions on installing and configuring the program.

I have installed MinGW, added it to environment path, used the following code in tasks.json:

```
  {
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "build",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "main.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
],
"presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "always",
    "focus": true,
    "panel": "shared"
 }
}
```

I have also tried adding the full path in my "tasks.json" file, and adding the MinGW path to my system variables as well.

The thing that is puzzling me is that my laptop compiles everything just fine even though everything that I check is exactly the same between my laptop and desktop.  Both run windows 10 v 1803, latest updates, both have MinGW installed in C:, environment variable path is the same "C:\MinGW\bin", and both use the same "tasks.json".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    cout<< "hello world! " << endl;

    cout<< "Hear me roar";


    return 0;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

P.S g++ -v works. forgot to put that.

Comment: If your mingw bin path is set properly, you would be able to do `g++ -v` from a command prompt - can you?

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart it so it will be able to access updated environment?